# Ao clicar em um botão, como fazer a tela deslizar pra baixo

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho uma área com preços, e tenho um botão logo ao lado "tenha mais detalhes", quero que ao clicar esse botão, a tela deslize lá pra baixo da página que é onde tenho a seção "contato". Queria saber como fazer pra ter esse "deslize"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anchors:

poe isso no botão:

`<a href="#anchor">botão</a>`

e onde vc quer ir você poe:

`<div id="anchor"></div>`

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Caso você queira que a tela deslize com animação, você pode utilizar o **jquery animate**.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#anchor").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Não utilize o atributo `name`, isso está *deprecated* na versão mais recente do HTML e a [resposta do J. Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157427/4808) pode não funcionar em navegadores mais recentes. Utilize `id`:

```html
<div id='meuelemento'> <!-- ... --> </div>
```

E no `<a>`:

```html
<a href='#meuelemento'> <!-- ... --> </a>
```